# Is act of zina considered kufr

Tags: zina, kufr

Assalamualaikum , I know zina is a very bad and a sinful act
Can you please tell commuting zina make one out of the pale of Islam or it make one kafir please answer whether it is or not

Comment: Please explain: Where is the relation to zina in your one line post? Elaborate your post and read [ask].

Comment: The act of "zina" is considered a grave sin and one must make sincere tawba to purify himself from filth and sins, but it doesn't make an individual a kafir, or take him out of the fold of Islam.

Answer (score 1):

No, committing a major sin is not kufr according to the Ahl al-Sunnah, unless one does so with the belief it is permitted or does it in order to scorn Allāh.

Imām Abu al-Thanā'a Maĥmūd ibn Zayd al-Lāmīshī al-Ĥanafī al-Māturīdī writes in Tamhīd li Qawāýid al-Tawĥīd:

**“The Ahl al-Sunnah have said: The one who commits a major sin from among the believers, if he committed it considering it to be permissible, or to scorn the one who forbade it [Allāh], or with the intention of rebelling [against Allāh], then indeed he disbelieves in Allāh táālā!
And if he committed it due to overpowering of lust, or he was lazy, or he was angry, or pride, or disdain [towards other Muslims] and he fears that Allāh táālā may punish him for it, and he hopes for His Mercy and His Forgiveness in that, then he is called a sinful believer.
The verdict on him is that if he repents, it will be forgiven. If he dies before Tawbah then for him is what Allāh táālā has willed:
If He wills, He may forgive him by His Grace and Mercy or by the intercession of a Nabī or a Walī from among His slaves, and if He wills, He can punish him due to his crime, then enter him into paradise.”**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o Allaikum.

Zinda is indeed a major sin but this is not called kufr. Kufr in simple words means to disbelief in Allah.